# Filter object with type=? in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filter

Here is the data type:

```
data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Orange
data Basket = Basket Fruit Int
```

now in the code ,there is a list of `Basket` which could have any of `Fruit` inside. How to filter out all the `Baskets` with `Apple` in it ? in Python there is a function `type` or `instanceof` that may help but not sure how Haskell can handle this ?

```
baskets = [Baseket (Apple 10),Baseket (Banana 2),Baseket (Apple 6)]
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working? Your `Basket` data type should be `data Basket = Basket Fruit Int`, and then the objects are `Basket Apple 10`.

Comment: The important thing to know is that `Apple` etc. are not _types_, they're _data_.  You're not trying to look for "what is the type of this object," because the type of this object is `Fruit`.  You're trying to look for values of type `Fruit` that are _equal to_ `Apple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are a couple of typos in your code. If `Basket` is meant to have a fruit *and* and integer inside it, then it should be

```
data Basket = Basket Fruit Int
```

Second, the constructor for `Basket` should be called with two arguments and no parentheses around the arguments, so your list is

```
baskets :: [Basket]
baskets = [Basket Apple 10, Basket Banana 2, Basket Apple 6]
```

Finally, you use the word "filter" so I suspect you've already surmised that the operation you're looking for is the [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function.

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

In your case, `a ~ Basket`. So we need to give it a mapping from baskets to `Bool` which returns true if (and only if) the basket has apples in it. Since we're comparing fruits for equality, we need an `Eq` instance on `Fruit` (technically, we could pattern match, but since `Fruit` is clearly an enumeration to begin with, it should have `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, and all of the nice instances).

```
data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Orange deriving (Eq)
```

Now our `filter`.

```
appleBaskets :: [Basket]
appleBaskets = filter (\(Basket fruitType _) -> fruitType == Apple) baskets
```

We *destructure* the `Basket` inside of the lambda using pattern matching and then compare the fruit type against the `Apple` value.

Comment: `[ basket | basket@(Basket Apple _) <- baskets ]`

Comment: @Iceland_jack By all means, post another answer explaining the syntax, and I'll upvote it. I personally don't really like list comprehensions and will favor `map` / `filter`, but it would be a valuable addition to this page.

Comment: @Iceland_jack I think the original question wanted `fruitType /= Apple` instead of `fruitType == Apple` as in this answer. That switch is much harder to do with your technique.

Comment: I misread the question then, my solution only makes sense for the opposite